Creating Zotero folders based on citations organised by section
I want to automatically create a Zotero folder structure structured by markdown sections. # for folder ## for subfolder. And then for every citation used using Pandoc [@author2000] I want it to appear in the folder for that section.
It would automatically make a correctly organized Zotero library for every academic article I write and thus be very helpful as a look-up.
Does such a tool exist or something similar?
If not, does a tool that just creates a Zotero folder for a whole project using all citations in a document without the subfolders?

It doesn't exist AFAIK, but you could try to modify the section-bibliographies filter to do this.
